# Stored procedure taking a lot of time

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in my database. When I am calling that stored procedure, sometimes it takes 1 minute, sometimes it takes 10 minutes, and other times it takes even more than that to complete.

The below step alone taking more time in the whole process, not sure if this poor query and need to re-write the stored procedure or some other server issue

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 
            FROM table1 PWI (NOLOCK)
            INNER JOIN table2 W (NOLOCK) ON PWI.ID = W.ID
            WHERE W.Flag = 1
              AND PWI.PatID IN (SELECT PatID FROM @table3)
              AND W.SubID IN (SELECT SubID FROM @table4)))
```

Please help to fix this issue

Comment: Execution plan?

Comment: For starters you should get rid of those NOLOCK hints. They are not a great idea 99.999% of the time. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Table definition (including indexes), execution plan, approximate row counts would all be very helpful here.

Comment: I would try to reconfigure the IN statements as INNER JOINS and checking for NOT NULL. Also make sure the joined fields are indexed.

Comment: Thanks for your help ..Estimated execution plan?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

table variable get estimate row = 1 and plan build with loop join. use temp table or OPTION(RECOMPILE)

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. And it isn't clear what you are trying to say here.

Comment: On changing the table variable into #temp table fixed my issue. now the SP is running only 19 secs where it took 13 mins previously . thank you

Comment: Don't use table variable without much need :)

Answer (score 0):

Hart to tell without all the code and DDL, but this may improve the performance

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 
FROM table1 PWI (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN table2 W (NOLOCK) ON PWI.ID = W.ID
inner join @table3 on PWI.PatID = @table3.PatID
inner join @table4 on W.SubID = @table4.SubID
WHERE W.Flag = 1))
```